# Common queries for Location Sharing

Tags: geospatial, social-media

I am wondering whether there exist some datasets where users are explicitly asking to share their location to some friends, family members, colleagues.

The examples can be something like:

```
* share my location with jim
* let theresa know where am i
* stop sharing my location
```

Ideally this would be spoken data to a mobile device.